# Generic Interface polymorphism casting error

Tags: java, generics

Following, is a very simple example.
Why do I need to use casting  at `(String)classA.getOut();`

Compiler should now that type is String.

Thanks

```
ITest classA = new CLASSA();
String str = classA.getOut(); //Casting error

class CLASSA implements ITest<String> {
    public String getOut() {
        return "X";
    }
}

interface ITest<T> {
    public T getOut();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using **raw-types** instead of generics.

When you do

```
ITest classA = new CLASSA();
```

the compile-time type is an raw `ITest`, which replaces the `T` with `Object` and so introduces a method with signaure

```
public Object getOut()
```

This is why the compiler forces you to cast the `Object` to `String` (the compiler doesn't know that at Runtime the method would return an object that is compatible with `String`).

---

A proper way of getting rid of the warning and the casting error is using Generics instead of raw types:

```
ITest<String> classA = new CLASSA();
```

Comment: Thanks, and when I declare CLASSA , can I do like this: `class CLASSA implements ITest` , instead of `class CLASSA implements ITest<String>` ?

Comment: References to generic types should be parameterized, so leave it as it is now.

Comment: But what will happen if not, I am not getting any compile errors or warnings.

Comment: It will compile, but you will get a warning only

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `classA` as a raw type. This means that the compiler doesn't know that it's `getOut()` method will return a `String`. Change your declaration to:

```
ITest<String> classA = new CLASSA();
```

Answer (score 0):

The "interface type" of the variable `classA` is `ITest` and neither `ITest<String>` nor `CLASSA` so all the compiler knows that it has a method `getOut` of a raw (undefined) type.